# How to view an app's user license agreement?

Tags: iphone, applications

How can I view an iPhone app's user license agreement? I'd like to know the answer to the general case, but also specifically concerning [this app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/genki-vocab-cards-japanese-words-essential-for-beginners/id785207187?mt=8).

Answer (score 1):

The way that the license agreements appear differs between developers.

Here is an example of it being contained at the links at the bottom at the page of the app in the app store (iOS):

[image: links]

On the Mac, it is on the left sidebar:

[image: mac liscence]

Another one with the links in the description:

[image: description]

If an App is available through the App Store and it doesn't have a EULA, then the [default App EULA in the App Store Terms and Conditions](https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/uk/terms.html#APPS) will apply, which is:

> Apps made available through the App Store are licensed, not sold, to
>   you. Your license to each App is subject to your prior acceptance of
>   either this Licensed Application End User License Agreement (“Standard
>   EULA”), or a custom end user license agreement between you and the
>   Application Provider (“Custom EULA”), if one is provided. Your license
>   to any Apple App under this Standard EULA or Custom EULA is granted by
>   Apple, and your license to any Third Party App under this Standard
>   EULA or Custom EULA is granted by the Application Provider of that
>   Third Party App. Any App that is subject to this Standard EULA is
>   referred to herein as the “Licensed Application.” The Application
>   Provider or Apple as applicable (“Licensor”) reserves all rights in
>   and to the Licensed Application not expressly granted to you under
>   this Standard EULA.
>
> a. Scope of License: Licensor grants to you a nontransferable license
>   to use the Licensed Application on any Apple-branded products that you
>   own or control and as permitted by the Usage Rules. The terms of this
>   Standard EULA will govern any content, materials, or services
>   accessible from or purchased within the Licensed Application as well
>   as upgrades provided by Licensor that replace or supplement the
>   original Licensed Application, unless such upgrade is accompanied by a
>   Custom EULA. Except as provided in the Usage Rules, you may not
>   distribute or make the Licensed Application available over a network
>   where it could be used by multiple devices at the same time. You may
>   not transfer, redistribute or sublicense the Licensed Application and,
>   if you sell your Apple Device to a third party, you must remove the
>   Licensed Application from the Apple Device before doing so. You may
>   not copy (except as permitted by this license and the Usage Rules),
>   reverse-engineer, disassemble, attempt to derive the source code of,
>   modify, or create derivative works of the Licensed Application, any
>   updates, or any part thereof (except as and only to the extent that
>   any foregoing restriction is prohibited by applicable law or to the
>   extent as may be permitted by the licensing terms governing use of any
>   open-sourced components included with the Licensed Application).
>
> b. Consent to Use of Data: You agree that Licensor may collect and use
>   technical data and related information—including but not limited to
>   technical information about your device, system and application
>   software, and peripherals—that is gathered periodically to facilitate
>   the provision of software updates, product support, and other services
>   to you (if any) related to the Licensed Application. Licensor may use
>   this information, as long as it is in a form that does not personally
>   identify you, to improve its products or to provide services or
>   technologies to you.
>
> c. Termination. This Standard EULA is effective until terminated by
>   you or Licensor. Your rights under this Standard EULA will terminate
>   automatically if you fail to comply with any of its terms.
>
> d. External Services. The Licensed Application may enable access to
>   Licensor’s and/or third-party services and websites (collectively and
>   individually, "External Services"). You agree to use the External
>   Services at your sole risk. Licensor is not responsible for examining
>   or evaluating the content or accuracy of any third-party External
>   Services, and shall not be liable for any such third-party External
>   Services. Data displayed by any Licensed Application or External
>   Service, including but not limited to financial, medical and location
>   information, is for general informational purposes only and is not
>   guaranteed by Licensor or its agents. You will not use the External
>   Services in any manner that is inconsistent with the terms of this
>   Standard EULA or that infringes the intellectual property rights of
>   Licensor or any third party. You agree not to use the External
>   Services to harass, abuse, stalk, threaten or defame any person or
>   entity, and that Licensor is not responsible for any such use.
>   External Services may not be available in all languages or in your
>   Home Country, and may not be appropriate or available for use in any
>   particular location. To the extent you choose to use such External
>   Services, you are solely responsible for compliance with any
>   applicable laws. Licensor reserves the right to change, suspend,
>   remove, disable or impose access restrictions or limits on any
>   External Services at any time without notice or liability to you.
>
> e. NO WARRANTY: Licensor will use reasonable care and skill with
>   respect to the provision of the Licensed Application and any External
>   Services performed or provided by the Licensed Application to you.
>   Licensor does not make any other promises or warranties about the
>   External Services and in particular does not warrant that:
>
> (i) your used of the External Services will be uninterrupted or
>   error-free;
>
> (ii) the External Services will be free from loss, corruption, attack,
>   viruses, interference, hacking, or other security intrusion, and
>   Licensor disclaims any liability relating thereto. You shall be
>   responsible for backing up your own system, including any Licensed
>   Application that is stored on your system.
>
> f. Limitation of Liability.
>
> (i) Except as set out in section (ii) hereunder, in no case shall
>   Licensor, its directors, officers, employees, affiliates, agents,
>   contractors, principals or licensors be liable for any loss or damage
>   caused by Licensor, its employees or agents where:
>
> (1) there is no breach of a legal duty of care owed to you by Licensor
>   or by any of its employees or agents;
>
> (2) it is not a reasonably foreseeable result of any such breach;
>
> (3) any increase in loss or damage results from breach by you of any
>   term of this End User Licence Agreement ("Agreement");
>
> (4) it results from a decision by Licensor to warn you, to suspend or
>   terminate your access to the External Services, or to take any other
>   action during the investigation of a suspected violation or as a
>   result of Licensor’s conclusion that a violation of this Agreement has
>   occurred;
>
> (5) it relates to loss of income, business or profits, or any loss or
>   corruption of data in connection with your use of the Licensed
>   Application.
>
> (ii) Nothing in this Agreement removes or limits Licensor’s liability
>   for fraud, gross negligence, wilful misconduct, or for death or
>   personal injury caused by its negligence.
>
> g. You may not use or otherwise export or re-export the Licensed
>   Application except as authorized by United States law and the laws of
>   the jurisdiction in which the Licensed Application was obtained. In
>   particular, but without limitation, the Licensed Application may not
>   be exported or re-exported (a) into any U.S.-embargoed countries or
>   (b) to anyone on the U.S. Treasury Department's Specially Designated
>   Nationals List or the U.S. Department of Commerce Denied Persons List
>   or Entity List. By using the Licensed Application, you represent and
>   warrant that you are not located in any such country or on any such
>   list. You also agree that you will not use these products for any
>   purposes prohibited by United States law, including, without
>   limitation, the development, design, manufacture, or production of
>   nuclear, missile, or chemical or biological weapons.
>
> h. The Licensed Application and related documentation are "Commercial
>   Items", as that term is defined at 48 C.F.R. §2.101, consisting of
>   "Commercial Computer Software" and "Commercial Computer Software
>   Documentation", as such terms are used in 48 C.F.R. §12.212 or 48
>   C.F.R. §227.7202, as applicable. Consistent with 48 C.F.R. §12.212 or
>   48 C.F.R. §227.7202-1 through 227.7202-4, as applicable, the
>   Commercial Computer Software and Commercial Computer Software
>   Documentation are being licensed to U.S. Government end users (a) only
>   as Commercial Items and (b) with only those rights as are granted to
>   all other end users pursuant to the terms and conditions herein.
>   Unpublished-rights reserved under the copyright laws of the United
>   States.
>
> i. Except to the extent expressly provided in the following paragraph,
>   this Agreement and the relationship between you and Apple shall be
>   governed by the laws of the State of California, excluding its
>   conflicts of law provisions. You and Apple agree to submit to the
>   personal and exclusive jurisdiction of the courts located within the
>   county of Santa Clara, California, to resolve any dispute or claim
>   arising from this Agreement. If (a) you are not a U.S. citizen; (b)
>   you do not reside in the U.S.; (c) you are not accessing the Service
>   from the U.S.; and (d) you are a citizen of one of the countries
>   identified below, you hereby agree that any dispute or claim arising
>   from this Agreement shall be governed by the applicable law set forth
>   below, without regard to any conflict of law provisions, and you
>   hereby irrevocably submit to the non-exclusive jurisdiction of the
>   courts located in the state, province or country identified below
>   whose law governs:
>
> If you are a resident of any European Union country or Switzerland,
>   Norway or Iceland, the governing law and forum shall be the laws and
>   courts of your usual place of residence.
>
> Specifically excluded from application to this Agreement is that law
>   known as the United Nations Convention on the International Sale of
>   Goods.

It seems that your app uses the default EULA.

Comment: Thanks. You wrote: 'Here is an example of it being contained at the links at the bottom'. The bottom of what?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, I was talking about the page of the app

Comment: You mean the app's page in iTunes or Apple Store?

Comment: Yes, I was talking about that, but it is for App Store on the iPhone only, not the Mac App Store

Comment: Thanks. Another point: the default App EULA you linked to is UK-specific, as indicated by the following sentence in the first section, 'A, INTRODUCTION TO OUR SERVICES': "By creating an account for use of the Services in the United Kingdom you are specifying that as your country of residence for tax purposes (“Home Country”), and our Services are available for your use in your Home Country." Where can I find the default EULA for other countries?